# How to retry mobile browser geo location after permission denied

Tags: javascript, web

My web page asks for the user's location by calling navigator.geolocation which in turn will ask the user to give permission.  If permission is denied, I offer an alternate method by selecting the location from a map.  But what if the user clicks "no" by mistake?  Is there any way to offer a second chance?

Comment: You'll have to display a popup that shows a user exactly how to re-enable/grant permission by themselves because it's designed that way (thankfully).

Comment: Not unless the user clears the setting using the browser's built in tools. Otherwise sites could just keep spamming users with permission requests if they don't get the answer they want

Comment: "display a popup that shows a user exactly how to re-enable/grant permission by themselves " sounds like a good solution but how does the user do that?

Comment: you'd have to just display a popup (using JavaScript) which points the user to the documentation for their browser - how you clear the browser's record of the user's permissions choices for any particular website will be different depending on the browser. e.g. [here are some suggestions for doing it in Chrome](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+reset+geolocation+permission&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=chrome+reset+geolo&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.4908j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: It's not something your application can do directly via code (for the reasons discussed), the user must do it. All you can do is provide them with the guidance (or links to the guidance) on what they would need to do. Detecting what browser the user is using is an art form in itself so you might be best to just provide a set of links for the most populate browsers.